# Jekyll add file to _site without extension

Tags: jekyll, netlify

In Netlify to [redirect a default Netlify subdomain to a primary domain](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) I need to add a `_redirects` file to the root of my `_site` folder.

In the root of my Jekyll project I've added a file named `_redirects` (no extension), but when my `_site` is generated it ignored the file and nothing is created, no file, no folder and page. How do I move a file with no extension into my `_site` directory?

I've added numerous static files with extensions without an issue, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Netlify redirects documentation](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) :

> ... (For Jekyll, this requires adding an include parameter to _config.yml.)

```
include:
  - ...
  - _redirects
```

Comment: this is the proper way to do it.  however, there are other less elegant ways, such as renaming your redirects to redirects.txt and changing your Netlify build command to something like `jekyll build && cp redirects.txt _site/_redirects` to do it "without jekyll's help"